# serverless offline and express route not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, serverless

i have 2 routes in my code, but always call the first route.
I have tried several attempts but can't see what I am doing wrong. How to call the second route? My code is :

**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const app = express()

//first route
//always call this
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World!')
})

//the second route
//never call this
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello Test!')
})

module.exports.handler =  serverless(app);
```

**serverless.yml**

```js
# serverless.yml

service: Test

plugins:
  - serverless-offline 
    
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    WEBHOOK_URL: ""

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Run `express` on lambda? Also there is only a single route defined in your `yml`

Comment: already fixed : https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/issues/44

Comment: You need read more about `express route`, your express route will be register in order. `GET /` router will `catch` all GET method, it is reason why your `GET /test` never be call. You can register `GET /test` at first.